# Setting a cookie header with Angular 5

Tags: angular, cookies, angular5

I'm currently attempting to set a `Cookie` header with the following `HTTPInterceptor`:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Cookie': 'session=' + this.cookieService.get('session'),
        'withCredentials': 'true',
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }

}
```

When attempting to set the `Cookie` I get the following error:

> Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"

I'm making the request to a local `Flask` API.

I have attempted to manually set the headers with `HTTPHeaders` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390835/set-cookie-in-request-headers-angular2) and also tried to set `xhr2.prototype._restrictedHeaders.cookie = false;` shown [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15730). All to no avail. Any idea how I can set the cookie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I found the solution to my question, hopefully this will help others with the same problem. It turns out I was setting `withCredentials` incorrectly and should be set as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }

}
```

When it is set like this, [angular](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#withCredentials) will automatically find the associated cookies and send them with the request

Comment: i'm not geeting your solution.. can you explain to send Cookie in headers my code

let headers ={
      "Cookie": "SSESS73554443e42d95902727fec19444e32b=P8-V7jJunbv2V0AaYl1joiM7QYxgOBVk_nll0Fwur-M",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "xT8MNNQsX3kJaq_1YSO06iVP2eefm9sE_PgPCAJX2ko",
    }
return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl + `mobileapp/file.json`, user , {headers:headers} );

Comment: Hi, but where do you set the cookie? You modified withCredentials, but now where are you setting the cookie header?

Comment: @Usr setting `withCredentials` tells the browser to send any cookies for that session along with the request - you don't have to manually add them